# Ajax Status == 0

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

Estou usando uma função em `ajax` para fazer algumas solicitações dinâmicas, mas o `req.status` está retornando `0` em vez de `200`.

O que pode ser?

Abaixo o código:

```
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
   else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

   // Arquivo PHP juntamente com o valor digitado no campo (metodo GET)
   var url = "http://177.55.99.146:8080/autenticacao/autentica?arquivo="+file;

   // Chamada do metodo open para processar a requisicao
   req.open("Get", url, true);

   // Quando o objeto recebe o retorno, chamamos a seguinte funcao;
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
     alert("Retorno do readyState == " + req.readyState + " readyStatus == " + req.status);
     if(req.readyState == 1) {      
        alert("Entrei no readyState == 1");
     }
     if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
         alert("Entrei no readyState == 4 e status == 200");
         // Resposta retornada pelo busca.php
         var resposta = req.responseText;
   }
```

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Comment: Não. O erro era outro.

Comment: Poderia postar qual era?

Answer (score 1):

O que pode estar acontecendo:

1. Cross-site scripting CORS (você está tentando acessar uma URL de
   dominio diferente do da aplicação)
2. A URL pode ser inacessivel.
3. Pode estar utilizando o protocolo errado, muitas vezes podemos estar
   testando usando o protocolo `file:\\\` ao invéz de `localhost:\\`.